# apache and nginx server showing problem on localhost

Tags: apache, nginx

I had already installed apache server on ubuntu 11.04 system. Now I installed Nginx server to have a ride. Now when I run http://localhost it is running nginx server but inorder to run apache server I have to use http://127.0.0.1. But I want both server to be run on http://localhost. Another thing when I am running localhost it is showing only Welcome to nginx! but not running any of application inside www folder. As I am new to Nginx I don't have any knowledge on it. So any help or suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about /var/www ??? If yes, then search for `index.html` file which is what being shown as a page when you browse http://localhost/.

Either remove this file or change default (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default) host's document-root to point to the folder where you have your application.

Also, make sure you have ports configured to run both `nginx` and `apache`. FYI, The default port for `HTTP` is 80.